# Why does Ubuntu resolve hostname but Win-10 does not?

Tags: windows-10, dns, ubuntu-16.04

I am pinging a network device with the syntax:

UBUNTU>> ping myHost

Ubuntu is able to resolve the hostname (myHost) to the correct LAN IP (192.168.XX.YY), whereas Win-10 is unable to do this unless a period is appended to myHost:

"Ping request could not find host myHost"

1) Is it unreasonable to expect myHost (sans period) to resolve on Win-10?

2) Why does Win-10 require the period appended to myHost? Why is the period required on Win-10?

Comment: Do you have a DNS or WINS server for your lan? Has your Ubuntu hosts file been configured with an address for myhost? My first guess is that the trailing . is forcing windows to use DNS for resolution, and skip NBT name resolution, but thats only valid if you are using a DNS server for your lan.

Comment: My LAN has a garden variety Asus RT-AC68U with Merlin's firmware.  I believe the router provides local DNS because I think that the Ubuntu box would need it to resolve 'myHost'.  The Ubuntu host file is not configured (stock).  Is there a command that can be issued at the router's command-line to answer Frank Thomas' questions?

Comment: If the W10 is using multiple adapters and/or multiple IP addresses from different subnets, it will cause this behavior. If this is the case, you will have to alter the default gateway or metric of the connections.

Comment: Good suggestions, that being said both are laptops and are on the same subnet with a single LAN IP address

Answer (score 0):

This single change allows the Windows 10 box to resolve (ping) the hostname to an IP address without the '.' appended to the hostname.

[image]